# meta-toolchain target build

Tags: yocto, toolchain

I am building `meta-toolchian` target of Yocto using the command `bitbake meta-toolchain`. I could see the following two folders are created under `tmp/sysroots-components`

- x86_64
- x86_64-nativesdk

I could see same libraries (bzip2, zlib ...) are built in both directories, but they are not same. I have checked using diff command.

Like these multiple same libraries are built in both the directories, can you guide me to understand the differences between two directories.

Comment: You have HOST and TARGET toolchain targets. For instance, if you need protobuf compiler to generate .h/.c files, you need it to run on build machine (host/native). In contrary, you also want to compile something to run on target machine.

Comment: my understanding of HOST and TARGET toolchain targets is,tools  required on the HOST PC(say X86) to build binary for the target(say ARM), tools required on the TARGET(say ARM) for building binary for the target(for ARM). I am building meta-toolchain image on 64-bit Intel machine running with Ubuntu. So my understanding is `x86_64` and `x86_64-nativesdk` both directories belongs to HOST. is it correct?

Comment: spent some more time on the bzip2 example updated in the beginning. I could see the the folder under `x86_64` is `bzip2-native` and under  `x86_64-nativesdk` is `nativesdk-bzip2`, but both are for x86 platform only(checked using file command). can you help me to know when the libraries/binaries built under `bzip2-native` are used and when the libraries/binaries built under `nativesdk-bzip2` are used.

Comment: @Nayfe can you help to understand when the bzip binary/library under bzip2-native and nativesdk-bzip2 were used.

Comment: Not sure, maybe it's related to [SDKMACHINE](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-SDKMACHINE) selection, but in most of cases, SDK runs on same architecture as build machine?